# Could not find the main class simplified

Tags: java, command-line

Been a while since I wrote command prompt applications, so am having some basic issues getting it to run. I am simplifying the problem as the original problem was using an executable jar file.

I have my class PortServer that contains a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new PortServer();
}
```

I then unrolled my jar file. Here is the output for my current directory:

```
thomash@thomash:~/portserver$ find -name PortServer.class
./com/blah/portserver/PortServer.class
```

I then try to run:

```
thomash@thomash:~/portserver$ /opt/java8/bin/java -cp . com.blah.portserver.PortServer
Error: Could not find or load main class com.blah.portserver.PortServer
```

Whiskey, Tango, Foxtrot?

Comment: While creating a jar file you need to create a manifest file which informs the runtime where the main is.

Comment: @Shriram Not running from a jar file. Did you read my post?

Comment: why are u giving -cp . in your execution. Because if you are using any libraries you need to give .  Can you try it out without cp variable.

Comment: Does `PortServer` is declared as a `public class` ?

Comment: @Shriram Because I'm trying lots of things to figure this out. I removed the -cp with no change.

Comment: @cheseaux Yes it is. I double checked. Thanks for asking a good question.

Comment: @duffymo Please review the details I provided showing the location of PortServer from my current directory and the -cp parameter to match up to it. If these are incorrect, please give me a reason why.

Comment: can you provide a simple class (i.e. an empty class with a main) which reproduces your problem?

Comment: You are using `-cp .` so `PortServer` will be searched in the current directory and not `com/blah/portserver`

Comment: Did you defined package correctly, like this: `package com.blah.portserver`?

Comment: @duffymo as you can see he is in the `~/portserver/` directory which contains `com/blah/portserver/Portserver.class`. So it looks all fine.

Comment: @duffymo the output of find shows that there is a `com/blah/portserver/PortServer.class` in `~/portserver/`. So there is a `com` directory in `~/portserver/`.

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote and request to close, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I guessed at just before Absurd-Mind was headed down that path, was that my main class extended and implemented other classes that were not in the classpath.

I tracked down all of the classes used and added them to the classpath and started getting other class not found exceptions, which I expected.

Now you know.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Thanks for the feedback. Would you mind terribly upvoting me? Someone downvoted this question and my answer and voted to close. I feel this was an important piece of information that i couldn't find anywhere on the web.